# How did they get 240V from one leg (L1)?

Tags: power, ac, phase

A neighbor lost his L2 connection to his house. The symptoms were as expected. Fifty percent of the lights and outlets did not work and all his 240V appliances (AC, fryer) did not work. The utility company Xcel came out and installed a "black box" that gave him back his 120V to the entire house.

What I figured they did was they disconnected L2 and just added a jumper from L1. This would mean he would have 120V throughout the house, but not 240V.

Nope, he had AC and he showed me the box they attached to the meter.

So, I am wondering what this black (yellow) box is.

Somehow Xcel created a second 120V out of phase 180-degree L2.

I can only think of two ways.

1. The are using the 120V and a VFD to create L1 0-degree and L2 180-degree.
2. The box has two transformers. Convert 120V to 60V with a center tap ground and then convert the 60V L1 and L2 up to 120V.

If you know what is in the "black box" can you include a link so I can find out more about this?

Comment: I will take a SWAG and assume it is a 1:1 transformer with one side connected to the L1 phase and neutral.  On the secondary connecting one end to neutral the out phase end will supply L2. If it is connected backwards you will just get a duplicate of L1.  You did not state which country but in the US you normally have a 240V secondary that is center tapped with the center being neutral. Hence from neutral to either phase 120, from phase to phase 220.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSCGKI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two possible solutions using off-the-shelf transformers.*

- (a) shows a single-phase transformer connected so that the output is out-of-phase with the input. (Note the dots on the primary and secondary coils.) This produces 120 V between each phase and neutral and 240 V between phases.
- (b) shows a similar solution using a centre-tapped transformer which may or may not have a secondary winding (which isn't required). Here voltage on the top half of the transformer induces a voltage on the bottom half.

Note that L1 will have to supply twice the current. This will result in some voltage drop and heating of the supply line but is probably deemed OK for a temporary fix.

---

> I don't see how (b) would change the phase to create L2 by simply running it through a primary coil with a center tap.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqvls6.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. (a) The original again and (b) the same circuit rearranged.*

If you're willing to believe that Figure 1a or 2a works then have a look at 2b. Here I've just taken the secondary coil and moved it round to the "primary side" of the schematic representation. On the real transformer they're still on the same core and nothing has changed.

The reason it works is that the P winding is energised by L1-N and the S winding is energised by transformer action. It *is* important that the phasing is maintained - note the dots on XFMR1 which show the relationship between the voltages. If we swap the secondary winding orientation then L2 would be in phase with L1 and you'd have L1-N = 120 V and L2-N = 120 V but L1-L2 = 0 V.

Comment: I did not realize it could be done using a 1:1 coil. I get circuit (a) that L2 will be 180 degrees out of phase. I don't see how (b) would change the phase to create L2 by simply running it through a primary coil with a center tap.

Comment: See if the update helps. My answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/566254/center-tap-transformer-voltages-180-out-of-phase-but-what-about-direction-of-cu/566261#566261 may help further.

Comment: Thanks. You nailed it with the visual. One additional curiosity. If an appliance that draws five amps at 240v, does that mean that the draw on L1 - N on the primary is ten amps? I wondered since he has several 50-amp breakers and AC units are running 24x7. I suspect the unit has internal breakers to limit the load on the single L1 line.  Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to address that with my comment, "Note that L1 will have to supply twice the current." "*If an appliance that draws five amps at 240v, does that mean that the draw on L1 - N on the primary is ten amps?*" Yes, you are correct. We can confirm that by calculating the power: \$ P = VI = 240 \times 5 = 120 \times 10 = 1200 \ \text W \$.

Answer (score 1):

a 1:1 autotransformer will do that.

connect neutral to the middle and the phase to one end, and the transformwer will make a mirror-image of the phase on the other end,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbhant.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You don't say anything about how large or heavy the box is, two critical lapses in information.

If it is indeed large and heavy, it could be nothing more than one high-power 1:1 transformer, sometimes called an isolation transformer in catalogs.  Powered by L1, there are only two options for connecting the secondary to the L2 feed point, in phase or out of phase with the primary (L1).

If in phase, then it is as you describe above, a second L1 phase; 120 V things work, 240 V things don't.   If it is connected out of phase, they you have standard 2-phase house power and everything works.

Comment: Box has decent tires, so I suspect it is about 100 lbs.  It is about h24" x w17" x d12". Going by your comments and others it appears it would contain a single transformer that can create the out of phase L2 at 120v. Thanks